# How to get the value of an index in CheckedBoxList? C#

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

I am trying to get a value of an index in checkedbox value but it seems to null.

```
 myCheckedListBox.Items.Add("bla1");
 myCheckedListBox.Items.Add("bla2");
 myCheckedListBox.Items.Add("bla3");
 myCheckedListBox.Items.Add("bla4");
```

Now I want to get the value of index 2

the code is

```
string value = myCheckedListBox.Items[2].ToString();
```

and I expect the value = bla3 but it is null?

What am I missing?

Comment: myCheckedListBox.Items[2].ToString() is working fine for me

Comment: It SHOULD work. You have something really weird on your machine. Try cleaning the solution and recompiling it again. Close VS and restart and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
string value = myCheckedListBox.Items[2].ToString();
```

mhCheckedBox is not same as myCheckedListBox :)

Comment: @dotNET how do you know that `mhCheckedBox` has no items? Maybe it's not wpf checkbox class ;]

Comment: sorry typo mistake. I corrected it now. still the value is null

Comment: @wudzik: See my comment above. How do you know a control named `mhCheckedBox` even exists on the page.

Comment: Same code is working fro me , Please post your full code to elaborate your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

```
((DataRowView)checkedListBox1.Items[index])[0]
```